# Cannot include custom font into xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, custom-font

i am trying to include a custom font into my project but i just cannot appear to do that. I was able to do it in my pervious projects without a problem.

First of all, when i include a font in to xCode project it appears like this: [image]

I have tried alots of things, and I know the guidelines when adding a new font,I have read a lot of articles like this ([Common Mistakes With Adding Custom Fonts to Your iOS App](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/)) and done that several times with success, but now it just wont work.

Fonts are included in the project, they are in copy bundle resources and in the .plist file.

Also I have tried cleaning the project, deleting derivated data, I actually created the whole project from scratch, with no success...

xCode version is 6.4 
Font in question is Roboto but i couldn't include any other. 
Font type is .ttf but i have tried with .otf also.

Any help here?

Comment: what is the font file extention?

Comment: check your font name is correct or not, if you have a doubt install the rtf in fonts and check what is the font name its shows

Comment: Hey, font file extension is .ttf, the font in question is Roboto and I have already used it in my last project.

Comment: https://onlinefontconverter.com/ convert it to .otf instead of .ttf

Comment: Ok, i tried with onlinefontconverter and converted it to otf, but still the same thing, as soon as I move it to xcode it looks like [this](http://prntscr.com/8dwo7j)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your project name have any special characters in the name? That can cause problems. E.g. question marks...

Comment: Dude you are a god! I will think better next time when choosing a name. I had a question mark at the end of the name. And I am so mad that that kind of think could cause a mess like that. Thanks!